# Avoid redirection to HTTPS in ASP.Net Core 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, https

I have to test some scenarios in Production environment and to do so, I need to avoid the automatic redirection from HTTP to HTTPS that seems to happen in ASP.NET Core 5.

I've already tried to remove (or comment) the lines below:

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseHsts();
```

But IIS still automatically redirects from HTTP to HTTPS. I've read something about launchSettings.json, but I understood that it is used only for local environment.

The server is a Windows Server 2019, IIS version is 10.0.17763.1.

What else should I try?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Why can't you just access it via HTTPS in the first place? It seems you've got an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) here.

Comment: What's inside your `web.config` file?

Comment: Have you made sure to reset the HSTS setting in your browser?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I can't paste the whole web.config here because it has more characters than allowed, but it doesn't have anything about redirection. It has a `handlers` section, a `aspNetCore` section with `environmentVariable` inside of it. That's all. Let me know if you need something else.

Comment: @Xerillio No, I'll try that. Thanks.

Comment: @mason One of the causes that forces me to do so is that I've bought a SSL certificate and I need to test the TXT file provided me to guarantee I'm the app owner. But the URL to test it is in HTTP. Please, let me know if I'm doing something wrong with this modus operandi.

Comment: @user16735407 You can just test it normally or try DNS - this is a symptom of the https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: @user16735407 after removing `app.UseHttpsRedirection();
`, you can then remove the applicationUrl https reference from launchSettings.json, then deploy to iis, create a site with http rather than https. I think this will help.